# Question about using future in the past

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

Are both of these sentences correct?

> They hoped that he would finish his book by the end of the month.
>   They hoped that he would have finished his book by the end of the month.

I think that the first one is correct, but my teacher said that the secod one is correct. I do not understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both fully grammatical and fully idiomatic, and refer to exactly the same objective circumstances.

The difference, as is usual in the case of a perfect form, is **entirely** in how the speaker is choosing to present the temporal structure of what they are saying.

In *They hoped that he would finish his book by the end of the month*, they are looking forward from when they were hoping.

In *They hoped that he would have finished his book by the end of the month*, they are imagining themselves looking backward from the end of the month.

In this case, there is very little difference in meaning; sometimes the choice sets up an expectation about the time of following sentences.

**Edit**: Books4languages has suggested an alternative interpreation of the second, as a counter-factual conditional (implying that he didn't finish by the end of the month). I agree that this is a possible reading, but it is not the meaning that occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of these sentences are grammatically correct. You are using "would" in two different ways here:

**"Would finish": would for future in the past**

When talking about the past we can use would to express something that has not happened at the time we are talking about:

- He left 5 minutes late, unaware that the delay would save his life.
- We knew he would find somewhere to stay, regardless of not having any money; he would stay with a friend in the area.

**"Would have finished": would for conditionals**

We often use would to express the so-called second and third conditionals:

- If he had not left 5 minutes late, the delay would not have saved his life.
- He would have found somewhere to stay, regardless of not having any money; he would have stayed with a friend in the area.

As we can see, these sentences are in the past tense and convey the same information.

Comment: You're saying that the _would have_ could be a counter-factual conditional? You're right, but that interpretation truly never occurred to me.